# How to solve "no authentication available" problem for rust crates when using vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo

We are quite familiar with the following errors when using Cargo.

```
[ERROR rust_analyzer::lsp_utils] rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file /Users/calvin/tiflash/raft-engine/Cargo.toml, Some(Version { major: 1, minor: 64, patch: 0, pre: Prerelease("nightly") }): Failed to run `"cargo" "metadata" "--format-version" "1" "--manifest-path" "/Users/calvin/tiflash/raft-engine/Cargo.toml" "--filter-platform" "x86_64-apple-darwin"`: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:     Updating git repository `https://github.com/pingcap/rust-protobuf`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs`
error: failed to load source for dependency `raft-proto`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/tikv/raft-rs?branch=master

Caused by:
  failed to fetch into: /Users/calvin/.cargo/git/db/raft-rs-42b8049ef2e3af07

Caused by:
  failed to authenticate when downloading repository: git@github.com:tikv/raft-rs

  * attempted ssh-agent authentication, but no usernames succeeded: `git`

  if the git CLI succeeds then `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  no authentication available
```

By using the following commands, problem can be solved

```bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

However, how can we do this while using vscode? One way is to use command line to start vscode, but this is a not very neat solution.

I wonder if there are some configs in vscode or the rust-analyzer plugin that can help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find modifying `~/.cargo/config` can help:

```ini
[net]
git-fetch-with-cli = true
```